# android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907574/7166151)
It's explained there must keep Write External Storage permission must outside the application tag. I have already kept it outside.

I am putting my code here :

```
cvMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "DEMO_" + timeStamp;
        String path = createWorkingDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg";
        File fileTemp = new File(path);

        if (!fileTemp.exists()) {
            try {
                fileTemp.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Bitmap b = cvMain.getDrawingCache();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileTemp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fileOutputStream);
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cvMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

createWorkingDirectory() method :

```
private File createWorkingDirectory() {
        File directory = new   File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "demo");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        return directory;
    }
```

I am getting this error at specific createNewFile() method call time.
I have been kept Write permission inside manifest and runtime applied, even though getting this error.
What is the issue I could not understand? Please help me in this. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) when writing file in API level 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927322/java-io-ioexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-when-writing-file-i)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, Not same because there is asking for runtime permission. I have done with it. I have applied runtime permissiona and there is Write permission exist inside android manifest at proper position still I am getting this error. Why don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution regarding above issue.

```
cvMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "DEMO_" + timeStamp;
        String path = createWorkingDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg";
        File fileTemp = new File(path);

        if (!fileTemp.exists()) {
            try {
                fileTemp.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Bitmap b = cvMain.getDrawingCache();
        OutputStream stream = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri filePathUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "demoApp", fileTemp);
            try {
                stream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(filePathUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (stream != null) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, stream);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                stream = new FileOutputStream(fileTemp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (stream != null)
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, stream);
        }
        try {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cvMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

file_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="demoApp"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="demoApp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider" />    
</provider>
```

Added build.gradle(app)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```